# Xubuntu boot loader not showing while triple boot xubuntu, mint and windows 8

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, grub, boot-loader

Here is what I did
 1. I had mint and windows 8 installed on my laptop and wanted to install xubuntu also.

2. I converted my disk to `basic` and `GPT` as xubuntu installation wizard was not showing windows partition. After doing this step, I could install xubuntu
3. I installed xubuntu in a seperate ext4 partition and created 1MB for `Reserved BIOS boot area` and used the same `swap` of mint for xubuntu (Actually it took it by default and asked to format it)
4. When I restart, windows 8 loaded automatically. No option was shown to load mint nor xubuntu.
5. Then I tried to reinstall grub in xubuntu. I was installed sucessfully but then windows loaded by default as before.
6. I tired to reinstall grub in mint too. Grub installation was successful here also but again windows 8 loaded by default.

Here is the [image: screenshot] of my disk list shown using a live bootable usb drive. The 26 GB is where I installed xubuntu, 19Gb contains mint and 5.6 GB is the swap.

How do I fix this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after all the options that I had tried, I removed windows os and mint os which only gave the disk to load ubuntu mate os which eventually solved the problem.